# Validate that string contains only alphabets

Tags: java

I would like to validate the String and to ensure that the String contains only alphabets.

Here is my program and else part is getting printed

```
String myString = "hellothisisastring";
        String reg="[a-zA-Z]";

    if(myString.matches(reg)) 
        { 
        System.out.println("Yep!"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
    System.out.println("Nope!"); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your regex like

```
String reg="[a-zA-Z]+";
```

`+` will ensure that it matches string one and more time.